# (Hibernate) Can't add entity with many-to-many relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, entity

Basically, my goal is to have product and factory entity where relationship is many-to-many.
Factory must have some product, while product is not necessary associated with a factory. The problem is that when I try to add Product entity I get this error.

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10103 table: PRODUCT column: FACT_ID
```

This is my Application class. **I want to be able to save product to repository without giving it factory list** but I got that error, so **I tried adding what's in the comment but the same error remains**.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepo prodRepo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    Product one = new Product();
  /*
    List<Product> productList= new ArrayList<Product>();
    productList.add(one);

    SomeFactory factory_one = new SomeaFactory("one", productList);
    List<Factory> factoryList = new ArrayList<Factory>();
    factoryList.add(factory_one);

    one.setFactoryList(factoryList);
  */
    prodRepo.save(one);
}
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private List<Factory> factoryList = null;

    public Product() {}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROD_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId()                  { return id; }
    public void setId(int id)           { this.id = id; }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "productList", targetEntity = Factory.class)
    public List<Factory> getFactoryList() {
        return factoryList;
    }
    public void setFactoryList(List<Factory> f) {
        this.factoryList = f;
    }

}
```

SomeFactory.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="SOME_FACT")
public class SomeFactory extends Factory {
    private String name;
    private List<Product> productList;

    public SomeFactory() {}
    public SomeFactory(String name, List<Product> products) {
        this.name = name;
        this.productList = products;
    }

    @Column(name = "FACT_NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getName()             { return name; }
    public void setName(String name)    { this.name = name; }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PRODUCT",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FACT_ID", nullable = true),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROD_ID", nullable = false))
    public List<Product> getProductList() {
        return productList;
    }
    public void setProductList(List<Product> products) {
        this.productList = products;
    }
}
```

Factory.java

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Factory {
    int id;

    public Factory() {}

    @Id
    @Column(name="FACT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    int getId()                     { return id; }
    void setId(int id)              { this.id = id; }
}
```

Comment: The join table has the same name as the other entity is that intentional?

Comment: In your join you say `@JoinColumn(name = "FACT_ID", nullable = true)` however the column `FACT_ID` holds the primary key (see your `Factory` class) so it can never be `null`...

Comment: It worked when I changed the name of the table! Thanks a lot!!